# width line of HTML table not the same of header size

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an HTML table. The lines of the table are not the same as the header width. How to fix it ?
Which CSS should I put and where ? Sorry for the dummie question but I am not familiar with CSS.

This is an example of my HTML source code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="ressources/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>


    
      <div class="container">
      <table class="table table-responsive">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>€/GO</th>
        <th>L/GO</th>
        <th>€/Value</th>
        <th>L/Value</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody style="height:150px;  width: 100%;  display:block;overflow-y:auto">
      <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:blue;">
        <th scope="row">GR</th>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:blue;">
        <th scope="row">GR</th>
        <td>400</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>120</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:orange;">
        <th scope="row">DKV</th>
        <td>111</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for the help ! If could create a JSFiddle fork it will be great or simply put a portion of code which I should add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**, and let me know if it help you.

```
<style>
 th, td , tr{
    width:100px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `<tbody>` remove the display-block style [`display: block`]

Comment: Hello, If I remove the `display:block` attrbiute, my table can't scroll. I absolutly need a scrollable table. But indeed, if I remove it, the lines takes the entire width. How to fix that ?

Comment: you want to be able to scroll through the table body or the entire table?

Comment: Only the table content (I want to header stay at his place)

Comment: Since that table functionality is controlled by the `table`'s display style. I suggest you use something like flex-box for the whole table. It requires a bit more work but It will work better than forcing this to work

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="fr">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <link rel="icon" href="ressources/favicon.ico" />
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ressources/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/sign-in/signin.css" integrity="sha384-mKB41Eu6sQQvXR8fqvXcVe8SXodkH6cYtVvHkvLwE7Nq0R/+coO4yJispNYKy9iZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<style>
 th, td , tr{
    width:100px;
}

</style>
    <body>


        
          <div class="container">
          <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>€/GO</th>
            <th>L/GO</th>
            <th>€/Value</th>
            <th>L/Value</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody style="height:150px;  width: 100%;  display:block;overflow-y:auto">
          <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:blue;">
            <th scope="row">GR</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:blue;">
            <th scope="row">GR</th>
            <td>400</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>120</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="color:orange;">
            <th scope="row">DKV</th>
            <td>111</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>222</td>
            </tr>
            
          </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
          </body>
    </html>
```